# Is there a way to associate an array slice indices in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I am implementing a function for multiplication a matrix by a vector.

The matrix is stored in a CSR (Compressed Sparse Row) format:

```
type csr_matrix ! Compressed Sparse Row
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: row_offsets ! dimension(nrows + 1)
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: columns ! dimension(nnz)
    real(dp), dimension(:), allocatable :: values ! dimension(nnz)
end type
```

The code below successfully compiles and works correctly:

```
res = 0
do i = 1, size(b)
    associate( &
        lbound => A%row_offsets(i) + 1, &
        ubound => A%row_offsets(i + 1) &
        )
        res(i) = res(i) + dot_product(A%values(lbound:ubound), b(A%columns(lbound:ubound)))
    end associate
end do
```

The `lbound:ubound` expression appears twice so I thought it would be nice to refactor the code by replacing the associations for `lbound` and `ubound` with a single `slice_ind` association:

```
res = 0
do i = 1, size(b)
    associate(slice_ind => A%row_offsets(i) + 1 : A%row_offsets(i + 1))
        res(i) = res(i) + dot_product(A%values(slice_ind), b(A%columns(slice_ind)))
    end associate
end do
```

However the compiler produces an error:

```
error #5082: Syntax error, found ':' when expecting one of: ) ,
```

Is there a way to do this kind of association in fortran? If not, is there a better way to make the code more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, the code is invalid. You may only use `:` when making a subarray (array section) or in `::` in certain declarations and allocations.

You must use your version with scalar `lbound` and `ubound`. Generally, there is no way to store an array indexing expression (single ore more dimensions) in a variable or array. The exception is one-dimensional vector indexing where an array contains all the indexes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I can explicitly create a one-dimensional vector indexing array, but this would be an inefficient way of doing it.

Comment: Very inefficient.